# Role of non-empty boundary assumption in $L^2$ decomposition and Weyl's law

Tags: functional-analysis, differential-geometry, partial-differential-equations, spectral-theory

P. 8 of Chavel's book *Eigenvalues in Riemannian Geometry* lists several problems, one being:

[image]

Later, the author states the following two results:

[image]
[image]

**Question 1:** Is the assumption that $\partial M\neq\emptyset$ essential?

**Question 2:** Do the above two results still hold true if $U$ is, for example, an open submanifold of a closed Riemannian manifold $N$?

*Comments:* For Q2, it seems to me that since $L^2(U)\cong L^2(\overline U)$, there still exists an orthonormal basis for $L^2(U)$ consisting of eigenfunctions of $\Delta|_U$, and that the associated eigenvalues satisfy Weyl's law. On the other hand, there could be additional elements in the spectrum of $\Delta|_U$ in the absence of a boundary condition.